# number between 17 and 18, and has a rational square root

Tags: arithmetic, rational-numbers, radicals

"number between 17 and 18, and has a rational square root"
Is there even one?
They all keep coming up irrational for me

Comment: It would be more intruiging to know how you found the irrational ones.

Answer (score 25):

**Hint**: Can you think of a rational number between $\sqrt{17}$ and $\sqrt{18}$?

Comment: Perhaps to make it a little easier to see how to construct it:  you want to form a number $ \ \frac{p^2}{q^2} \ $ , $ \ p \ $ and $ \ q \ $ being integers and with the numerator and denominator relatively prime, that is between $ \ 17^2 \ = \ 289 \ $ and $ \ 18^2 \ = \ 324 \ $ .

Comment: We can also use continued fractions.  $\sqrt{17}=[4;\overline{8}]$ while $\sqrt{18}=[4,\overline{4,8}]$.  Hence the "simplest" answer is $[4;5]=4\frac{1}{5}=4.2$.

Comment: You can be as simple-minded as you like. Try $4.1$, $4.2$, $4.3$, etc., squaring each one, till you find one of the squares to lie between $17$ and $18$. In case you jumped over the interval $\langle17,18\rangle$, you could work on varying the second decimal place.

Comment: @vadim123:  Wouldn't the simplest answer be $[4,\overline{6,8}] = 2\sqrt{13/3}$?

Comment: @EricTowers, that is indeed simple, but alas not rational.

Answer (score 0):

I like the positive root of $x^2 - x - \frac{217745}{16384}$.

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: It's as good as any other?

Comment: It is an irrational liking.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there even one?" Yes – there are infinitely many. (*Exercise:* Why?)

*Hint:* Guess the square root, not the number between 17 and 18.